# Why does Array.from not work with Qualtrics(which uses JFE)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, qualtrics

If I use `Array.from()` method in a blank text qualtrics question, I do not get the expected output. Note that I believe Qualtrics implements javascript with JFE.

For example, the below code is some html that squares `[1,2,3]` with map and with Array.from().

- Map works, Array.from doesn't.
- (Note)I see the same behavior if I input the javascript separately in the qualtrics javascript editor (as opposed to inputting it together with the html as below)

  ```
  <p>The initial array before we square it is: <span id="initArr"></span> </p><br>

  <p>Squaring the numbers with map gives <span id="mapArr"></span></p><br>

  <p>Squaring the numbers with Array.from gives <span id="fromArr"></span></p>

       <script>

   let initArr = document.getElementById("initArr");
   let mapArr = document.getElementById("mapArr");
   let fromArr = document.getElementById("fromArr");

   let basicArr=[1,2,3];
   initArr.innerHTML = basicArr;
       mapArr.innerHTML = basicArr.map(x=>x*x);
       fromArr.innerHTML=Array.from(basicArr,x=>x*x);
       </script>
  ```

Produces the following output:
[image: qualtrics/JFE output example]

Comment: Interesting observation but it doesn't really make sense to use `Array.from()` on `basicArr` when it's already an array. Why are you doing so?

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say that `Array.from` has been implemented without the second `mapFn` argument

Comment: @Phil I'm guessing you're right, but I couldn't find anything about this in their documentation, which makes me worried about issues with other commands going unnoticed. As for why I'm using `Array.from()`. Short answer: I'm new to Javascript. Longer answer: In other cases `basicArr` may be sparse for me, in which case I *think* `map` isn't correct to use.